# How to load geojson instantly on the leaflet map while uploading it through html input form?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, geojson

I want to build the system that allows the client to upload the geojson files from html form and this data will show on the leaflet map. While I try to do so, It shows the error code 405. I want to submit the form containing geojson file and load this file using leaflet-omnivore plugin. 
My html file as,

```
<section class="addVectorLayer">
        <form action="" method="POST" class="vector">
            Click to add your vector layer. It support Json, Geojson, csv, gpx and kml formats.
            <input type="file" name="files" id="input_files">
        </form>
</section>
```

my js file is here,

```
geojson.onlode = function() {
    geojson.readAsDataURL(document.getElementById('input_files').files[0]);
    };
    omnivore.geojson(geojson.result).addTo(map);
```

Please note that I don't want async call.

Answer (score 1):

I added some code based on this plugin. That works for me little. The better way is highly appriciated.

```
var fileInput = document.getElementById('input_files');

   fileInput.addEventListener('change', function (event) {
      var file = fileInput.files[0],
         fr = new FileReader();
      fileInput.value = ''; // Clear the input.
      extention = file.name.split('.')[1]
      if (extention === 'geojson') {
         fr.onload = function () {
            var layer = omnivore.geojson(fr.result).addTo(map);
            map.fitBounds(layer.getBounds());
         };
         fr.readAsDataURL(file);
      }
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `fr.readAsText()`and JSON.parsing the result allows you to feed the result to L.geoJson(), no need for the omnivore plugin you are using.